# Get custom date time format in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have time saved in database like this 
`2016-01-30 14:36:00`

But I am using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and I want to convert the time as in this format

`2016-01-30T14:36:00`

So to get that format I tried like this

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(moment(date).parseZone().format());
```

but its showing date like this
`2015-12-21T15:20:04+05:30`

So can someone tell me how to get the time in that format in moment.js

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var dbDate = '2016-01-30 14:36:00';
var format = 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss';
var date = moment(dbDate, format);
var isValid = date.isValid() // true
console.log(isValid, date.year(), date.month(), date.date())
```

Comment: 0 - jan, 1 - fab and so on

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below code -

```
console.log(moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom format:

```
var date = moment();
var out = date.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
var currentDate = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
 //2015-12-21T15:50:28
```